# Show blob in svg image tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I create a temporary file in this way `$scope.imgData = URL.createObjectURL(curFile);`.

In my html file, I'm trying to display it inside an svg, but nothing is displayed. This is my html:

```
<svg width="780" ng-attr-height="625" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  style="cursor:crosshair; padding-top: 16px;" ng-mousemove="updateCoords($event)" >
    <image id="MyImg" xlink:href="" ng-href="{{ imgData }}" x="0" y="0" height="625px" width="780px"/>
</svg>
```

If I download the link inside `imgData` (something like `blob:http://localhost/397f996a-d456-4f25-b9ed-f210d2c38a57`), and open as jpg, I can see the image.

What's the problem?

Comment: does your server set the correct header for the content type?

Comment: If you want to embed the image use base64 enconding

Comment: @philipp I set the content type to image/jpeg but the result is the same... Converting to Base64 is slow for big images. I'd like to use that way similar to the <img> src

Comment: So you have binary image data in the markup?